# Loading and reading a JSON file for a value in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

This is my very first day learning Python (I do TypeScript and .NET). I am wondering if there is a way, like LINQ in .NET, to read and parse a JSON file for a particular value and when that value is found grab all those objects. I have a JSON file below and can load it with the following code but am trying to find the specific object value and get all it's data.

**JSON File**

```
{
   "10":{
      "objectId":10,
      "groups":[
         {
            "group":"GR100",
            "ages":[
               1,
               10,
               15
            ]
         },
         {
            "group":"GR201",
            "ages":[
               2,
               17
            ]
         }
      ],
      "connections":[
         {
            "group":"GR303",
            "ages":[
               40,
               51
            ],
            "groupCheck":true,
            "groupCheckExceptions":[
               "GR402"
            ]
         },
         {
            "group":"GR303",
            "ages":[
               1,
               2,
               3,
               4,
               5,
               6
            ],
            "groupB":"GR402",
            "agesB":[
               2,
               5
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "11":{
      "objectId":20,
      "groups":[
          { ... similar to above }
      ],
      "connections":[
          { ... similar to above }
      ]
   }
}
```

For the **JSON File**, these are the rules:

- *objectId* is required and unique, not null int
- *group* is required but can be empty

  - *group* is required and unique with *groups*, not null string
  - *ages* is required and unique with *groups*, not null comma separated ints
- *connections* is required but can be empty

  - *group* is required and unique with *connections*, not null string
  - *ages* is required and unique with *connections*, not null comma separated ints

    **REQUIRED (one or the other together)**
  - *groupCheck* is boolean
  - *groupCheckExceptions* not null comma separated string of group names

    **or**
  - *groupB* is unique, not null string (group and groupB can be the same)
  - *agesB* is not null comma separated ints

**Python File**

```
import json

# JSON objects
json_objects = None

with open("thejsonfile.json", "r") as file:
    json_objects = json.load(file)

# Need to find when an input comes in as an int (already have that part), like so where x is an int
input_object = x 

# then need to find out if that input_object is equal to an objectId in the file and bring in
# all it's data to the JSONClass
allMyObjects = JSONClass(**json_objects)
```

Still have to figure out the **JSONCLass** yet as remember this is my first day of Python. I want a list of groups and connections to use. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Couldn't help there's a `"` where there should be a `,` after `"ages": [40,51]`.

Comment: The shown JSON object consists of two attributes "objectId" (and others). This doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Duplicate keys are technically valid in JSON. `json.loads('{"foo": "bar", "foo": "baz"}')` won't raise any errors (but the resulting Python dictionary will only have the last value).

Comment: whoops sorry about the typos and brackets. fixing now.

Comment: @Selcuk: They're technically valid in Python, too.

Comment: @martineau Good point.

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you, I wasn't sure regarding JSON, therefore only the vague "doesn't make sense".

Comment: all updated now apologies to all